# Why doesn't Astra, a Kryptonian, know what Kryptonite is?

Tags: dc, arrowverse, supergirl, supergirl-2015

Near the end of Episode 2 of [Supergirl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supergirl_%28U.S._TV_series%29), Astra (a Kryptonian) says to Henshaw that humans have no weapons that can harm her, and then Henshaw surprises her by stabbing her with a blade of Kryptonite.  She flies off in pain and then later has the following conversation with a Kryptonian scientist who is analyzing the blade:

> Astra: Kryptonians are nearly indestructible on Earth. How could that blade hurt me?
>
> Scientist: Unclear. I've never seen anything like it. It's definitely not from this planet. It seems to be emitting a specific radioactivity that's damaging to your cellular structure.
>
> Astra: It's still making me sick. Get it away from me. Get it out of here.

I am not very familiar with the Superman canon, so I'd like to know why these two Kryptonians don't know what Kryptonite is.

Comment: http://entertainment.howstuffworks.com/arts/comic-books/kryptonite2.htm - Kryptonite isn't native to Krypton.

Comment: You'd be surprised how many Tellurians don't know what tellurium is.

Comment: Follow-up question: Why is the scientist able to handle it with impunity?  Are there non-Kryptonian aliens on Earth?

Comment: @PeregrineRook - Yes, it appears that there were a wide range of non-Kryptonian aliens on Fort Rozz. Supergirl has already fought two of them, an unnamed alien in the first episode and a Helgramite in the second episode.

Comment: Voting to close based on our future works policy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are actually two questions here.

### Why don't the Kryptonians know what Kryptonite is?

The very short answer is that Kryptonite is **not native to Krypton**, it was formed when Krypton was *destroyed*. Since she's been in hiding, it's very unlikely that Astra has ever encountered Kryptonite. Note that the very first time that Superman encounters the stuff (in [Superman v1 #61](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Superman_Vol_1_61)), he goes through precisely the same learning curve, discovering what it is, where it came from and why it diminished his powers.

[image]

### Why doesn't it affect the scientist?

We know from earlier in the episode that Fort Rozz was carrying other species than just Kryptonians, including a Helgramite. The expectation seems to be that that the overwhelming majority of aliens on board weren't Kryptonians at all, something that will allow Supergirl to fight a "*monster of the week*" without having to constantly overmatch other Super-beings.

It's quite possible certain that the scientist wasn't a Kryptonian at all but merely another *humanoid alien* from within the Kryptonian Empire, hence his unusual eyes

[image]